# Android: Bottom nav bar with equally space buttons

Tags: android, xml, layout, button, menu

Hi I'm trying to create a bottom nav bar for my application similiar to the iphone zappos app: [image]

I currently have a linear layout within my relative layout. The code is here:

```
    <LinearLayout 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="60dip"
android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/navhomebtn" 
    android:text="Home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    <Button 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/navsearchbtn" 
    android:text="Search" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    <Button 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/navfavbtn" 
    android:text="Favorites" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <Button 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/navloanbtn" 
    android:text="Loans" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I change the buttons to fill parent they just overlap each other and don't respect the others size. I was hoping to get them to fill the space so different size phones will all have a similar UI experience. Otherwise I would have to set them as fixed width and have it centered with a background that blends (which I don't want to do).

Please help!

Comment: why would you want to design an iphone-like layout for an android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use layout_weight of 1 in your LinearLayout and use 0dp for layout_width and 0.25 for layout_weight in your buttons.

Comment: from my tests, "layout_weight of 1 in your LinearLayout" is not necessary. BTW, your solution works ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use layout_weight on the buttons. Set all button's layout_weight to 1 and each will take 1/n of its parent's width.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing 0dip for each layout_width.

Answer (score 0):

As the other guys mentioned, the easiest way is to set the layout_width to 0dip and set the layout_weight.  An alternate approach would be to use a RelativeLayout instead, and manually set the layout_alignParentLeft/Right and layout_toLeft/Rightof.